# GraphDB Free 8.3: generate war files

Tags: graphdb

Is it still possible to generate war files in version 8.3 of graphDB?
I didn't find the generate-war-files file in my distribution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The support for war files was dropped officially in version 8.0, due to various deployment, logging and exception handling issues. GraphDB uses an embedded Tomcat which handles all the work.